# Jersey 1.x JAX-RS: General unhandled exception java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jax-rs, glassfish-3, jersey-1.0

We have a legacy API build on jersey 1.13 (`jax-rs 1.x`) and deployed to glassfish 3.1.2 server. We have multiple `ContainerRequestFilters` and the same are configured via `web.xml`. Below is a sample reference:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ApplyRestfulService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     .....
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.api.filter.CorsFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.api.filter.CorsFilter,
            com.api.filter.AuthenticationFilter,
            com.api.filter.AuthorizationFIlter
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

My understanding is the Request filter will execute in the order it has been defined above before calling the resouce  i.e.

first `CorsFilter` --> `AuthenticationFIlter` --> `AuthorizationFIlter` --> `Some API Resource`

Within the AuthenticationFilter we set custom securityContext object to `ContainerRequest` to be consumed in next Filter as below

```
@Provider
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class) ;
private static final String PREFIX_JWT = "JWT ";

@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
     AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = someJWTAuthenticationMethod(request);
     request.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer(authenticationResponse));
    
    return request;
}
```

Authorizer is a custom class which implements `SecurityContext`. The intension of setting the response in SecurityContext is to get it in the next Filter i.e `AuthorizationFilter`. We use the `@Context` annotation to read the `SecurityContext` as shown below

```
@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Context
private SecurityContext context;

@Inject
private SomeDAO someDAO;

@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        String accountId = ((AuthenticationResponse) context.getUserPrincipal()).getSomeId();
        UserPrincipal user = getUser(accountId);
        request.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer(user));
    }
    return request;
}
```

This all seems to work fine but many times we are getting below `Exception` when we try to access `SecurityContext` in AuthenticationFilter RequestFilter:

```
    [#|2021-03-02T07:24:55.486+0000|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-8080(5);|ERROR [http-thread-pool-8080(5)] - General unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.ThreadLocalHttpContext.getRequest(ThreadLocalHttpContext.java:82)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$2.invoke(WebApplicationImpl.java:287)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy226.getUserPrincipal(Unknown Source)
    at com.api.filter.AuthorizationFilter.filter(AuthorizationFilter.java:36)
    at com.api.filter.AuthorizationFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.filter(AuthorizationFilter$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1454)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
```

When we restart the glassfish server the issue gets resolved but that is more of just an workaround and not the real solution.
Could this be because `AuthenticationFIlter` is `ApplicationScoped` and when multiple threads are accessing the API causes the above error ?

Comment: This is such a weird implementation that they would have a setSecurtiyContext and not a getSecurityContext. Jersey 2 has this. I guess they realized how problematic this limitation was.

Comment: If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/javaee/jersey-1.x/blob/864a01d7be490ab93d2424da3e446ad8eb84b1e8/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/server/impl/ThreadLocalHttpContext.java) for ThreadLocalHttpCntext, you can see that the IllegalStateException is caused by a NullPointerException. Not really sure what would cause that though in your case. You should step your debugger through it to see what's causing it.